# rsync (or robocopy) from multiple computers - what happens?

Tags: backup, rsync, robocopy

If a Linux server has two different rsync jobs nightly for the same folder to two different destinations, do both destinations end up with the same end set of files?  Or does the first job run, and set something on the source folder/files that would cause the 2nd rsync job to not realize the daily changes/updates to the source?

Same for a Windows environment using something like robocopy, or even a "differential" backup using BUE or similar.

Does each "sync" compare the destination to the source and update the destination regardless of if it is synced multiple times to different destinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rsync: Both jobs are independent of each other. In standard settings, they compare file size and mod time for source and target, those doesn't get modified on the source.

I guess you think about the [Archive file attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) of the FAT filesystem, but rsync doesn't use something like that.